# Optimizing MySQL statement with lot of count(row) an sum(row+row2)

Tags: sql, mysql, optimization

I need to use InnoDB storage engine on a table with about 1mil or so records in it at any given time. It has records being inserted to it at a very fast rate, which are then dropped within a few days, maybe a week. The ping table has about a million rows, whereas the website table only about 10,000.

My statement is this:

```
select url
from website ws, ping pi 
where ws.idproxy = pi.idproxy and pi.entrytime > curdate() - 3 and contentping+tcpping is not null 
group by url 
having sum(contentping+tcpping)/(count(*)-count(errortype)) < 500 and count(*) > 3 and 
count(errortype)/count(*) < .15
order by sum(contentping+tcpping)/(count(*)-count(errortype)) asc;
```

I added an index on entrytime, yet no dice. Can anyone throw me a bone as to what I should consider to look into for basic optimization of this query. The result set is only like 200 rows, so I'm not getting killed there.

Comment: Please edit the description to show the schema (`CREATE TABLE` statements) of the relations being queried.

Comment: Please edit the description to show the output of the RDBMS's query explainer on this query.

Comment: I will do this when I get back to my home PC. For now I can tell this: There is only 1 primary key on each of the two tables, and it is an INT in both cases. The only indices are on those primary keys. I was wondering if I should create more indices in a certain way as the simple ones I created didn't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the absence of the schemas of the relations, I'll have to make some guesses.

- If you're making `WHERE a.attrname = b.attrname` clauses, that cries out for a `JOIN` instead.
- Using `COUNT(*)` is both redundant and sometimes less efficient than `COUNT(some_specific_attribute)`. The primary key is a good candidate.
- Why would you test `contentping+tcpping IS NOT NULL`, asking for a calculation that appears unnecessary, instead of just testing whether the attributes individually are null?

Here's my attempt at an improvement:

```
SELECT url
FROM website AS ws
    JOIN ping AS pi
        ON ws.idproxy = pi.idproxy
WHERE
    pi.entrytime > CURDATE() - 3
    AND pi.contentping IS NOT NULL
    AND pi.tcpping IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY url
HAVING
    SUM(pi.contentping + pi.tcpping) / (COUNT(pi.idproxy) - COUNT(pi.errortype)) < 500
    AND COUNT(pi.idproxy) > 3
    AND COUNT(pi.errortype) / COUNT(pi.idproxy) < 0.15
ORDER BY
    SUM(pi.contentping + pi.tcpping) / (COUNT(pi.idproxy) - COUNT(pi.errortype)) ASC;
```

Performing lots of identical calculations in both the HAVING and ORDER BY clauses will likely be costing you performance. You could either put them in the SELECT clause, or create a view that has those calculations as attributes and use that view for accessing the values.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try these out individually when I get a chance and see how they work.